# MVC asp net vb connect to other database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

currently i have this

```
Public Class ApplicationDbContext
    Inherits IdentityDbContext(Of ApplicationUser)
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema:=False)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Create() As ApplicationDbContext
        Return New ApplicationDbContext()
    End Function
```

How do i connect to another connection string using a method like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new constructor to `ApplicationDbContext` and pass `connectionstring` to the `IdentityDbContext` class. `IdentityDbContext` Constructor takes a Name Or ConnectionString, so you can pass the other connection string via constructor. For more information read [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identitydbcontext.identitydbcontext%28v=vs.108%29.aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext.)

```
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Diagnostics
Public Class ApplicationDbContext
    Inherits IdentityDbContext(Of ApplicationUser)
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema := False)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(connectionstring As String)
        MyBase.New("connectionstring")
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Create() As ApplicationDbContext
        Return New ApplicationDbContext()
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: So then via db.* i can access both dbs?

Comment: Why do you need to access both database at same time ?

Comment: I need to get data from an external database to the application

Comment: Any ideas? how can i do this?

Comment: I have not used IdentityDbContext, but from class usage perspective it seems this is possible.